# Javascript loop push into global array

Tags: javascript

1.I want to push id[i] into global array.After I pushed then it will be id.length numbers items in each array,but it will be error and says y is not a function.how to solve it?

2.the sendrequest in the bottom will send a xmlhttprequest to server,but I don't understand why it will run first and then the function(parResponse) will be fire after  tmpReadRequest.sendReadRequest(); has down.

Thanks a lot

```
    var tes0=new Array();
    var tes1=new Array();
    var tes2=new Array();
    var tes4=new Array();
    var tes5=new Array();
    function ReadValuePath(id, Variable,id_2) {
        var tmpReadCB = function(parResponse)
        {
            for (var tmpIndex = 0; tmpIndex < parResponse.length; tmpIndex++)
            {
                var tmpItemValue = parResponse[tmpIndex];//console.log(tmpItemValue);
                var tmpValue = (tmpItemValue.mItemValue) ? tmpItemValue.mItemValue : tmpItemValue.mItemResultId;
                if(document.getElementById(id[tmpIndex]) != null && document.getElementById(id_2[tmpIndex]).value != 0)
                {   
                    document.getElementById(id[tmpIndex]).value = parseFloat(tmpValue).toFixed(2);  
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        var tmpReadRequest = new OPCReadRequest("DE", tmpReadCB);
           for(var z=0;z<5;z++ ){
           for(var i = 0; i < id.length; i++)
           var y="tes"+z;
           y.push(id[i]);
            tmpReadRequest.addItem("ab", Variable[i]);
        }
}
    tmpReadRequest.sendReadRequest();
}
```

Comment: `y` is not an array therefore it does not have a `push` method hence your exception. Unless it is a global variable in which case is is being overwritten by `var y="tes"+z`.

Comment: how to access the global array var tes0 to 5??

Comment: You can use either the `window` object and a string literal or change your structure slightly so your array are in a object then use the string literal of that. So the first option would be `window[y].push(id[i])`;

Comment: but my purpose is to loop through the tes0~5 using the z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the global scope through a string literal like you are trying you can use the window object which is the current global scope.

So in your case it would be `window[y].push(id[i])`;

Another option would be to change you scructure slightly as personally i don't like accessing the window directly.

so you could define your arrays like

```
var arrays = {
    tes0: [],
    tes2: [],
    tes3: [],
    tes4: [],
    tes5: [],
}
```

and access them like:

```
arrays[y].push(id[i])
```

---

EDIT according to comments

So you want to access global variable in a loop. You are half way there. What your doing is building a string `y` which contains the property name then using that in the square brackets to access that property.

So with the `window` option that would be:

```
for(var z=0;z<5;z++ ){
    var y="tes"+z;
    for(var i = 0; i < id.length; i++)
        window[y].push(id[i]);
    }
}
```

or with the second object option

```
/*
    Because arrays is an object we can use Object.keys
    This will return an array of the keys in our object which we can loop over to access each one
*/
Object.keys(arrays).forEach(function(key) {
    for(var i = 0; i < id.length; i++)
        arrays[key].push(id[i]);
    }
});
```

Hope that helps explain

Comment: but my purpose is to loop through the tes0~5 using the z

Comment: Thanks a lot.I got it ,do you have any idea about the second?

Comment: I cannot find any docs on `OPCReadRequest` however it seems like most async API's. You pass it your function `tmpReadCB ` which it lloks like it will call once its task is complete. You start the task with `tmpReadRequest.sendReadRequest();` then it will call `tmpReadCB ` once complete with the result. Its a callback.

Comment: the result is not as I thought,it will push each id to each array,then all the array is look like the same,but what I want is to pust 1~5 to array1 push 6~10 to array2 like that,do you know how to do?

Answer (score 1):

"A variable declared outside a function, becomes GLOBAL.

A global variable has global scope: All scripts and functions on a web page can access it. " @ [Source](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Y is not an array so .push() won't work on it. @ [Source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)